# Cannot load into OS after install Ubuntu 15.10 with MAAS

Tags: 15.10, maas

After install Ubuntu Server 15.10 with "Multiple server install with MAAS" selection from the ISO, I cannot load into the Ubuntu linux OS after my server detected to boot from the harddisk. The screen just turns black (different from what I had when using 14.04). There is not "package manager" and "update manager" configuration during the OS installation.

I tried the same ISO without installing "MAAS" , it works. So I pretty sure there's a problem with MAAS installation.

May I know if there is anything I need to check or set before going to 15.10 with MAAS?